# Reactjs multiple fetch - TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I already have one fetch and want to get multiple fetch but the second fetch like can't read the data. It show "TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of undefined".

This is my code for one fetch :

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        ticker: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://vip.bitcoin.co.id/api/btc_idr/ticker")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                tickerBtcIdr: result.ticker
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
            });
        }
    )
}

render() {
    const {
        error,
        isLoaded,
        tickerBtcIdr,
    }  = this.state;
    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App"></div>
                <div className="Loading">
                    <Loading />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <AppBar />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>IDR MARKETS</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BTC/IDR</td>
                        <td>Bitcoin</td>
                        <td>{tickerBtcIdr.last}</td>
                        <td>{tickerBtcIdr.vol_idr}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}}
```

This work, but if i duplicate the fetch like :

```
    componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://vip.bitcoin.co.id/api/btc_idr/ticker")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                tickerBtcIdr: result.ticker
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
            });
        }
    )

    fetch("https://vip.bitcoin.co.id/api/bch_idr/ticker")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                tickerBchIdr: result.ticker
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
            });
        }
    )
}
```

And i render it :

```
    render() {
    const {
        error,
        isLoaded,
        tickerBtcIdr,
        tickerBchIdr,
    }  = this.state;
    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="App"></div>
                <div className="Loading">
                    <Loading />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <AppBar />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BTC/IDR</td>
                        <td>{tickerBtcIdr.last}</td>
                        <td>{tickerBtcIdr.vol_idr}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>BCH/IDR</td>
                        <td>{tickerBchIdr.last}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

}

It show "TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of undefined".

Comment: Debug your fetch function and check what does it return

Comment: It seems that `tickerBtcIdr` is undefined. That probably means that your fetch result json doesn't contain that key.

Comment: I thinks the undefined is tickerBchIdr, because if i remove the second fetch the code work fine. But i don't know how the make multiple fetch work together.

Comment: You don't use the `tickerBchIdr` state anywhere in your code, so why would it matter if that was undefined? Unless your actual render code is different from what you posted. All code seeking debugging help must have a `mcve` so we can reproduce the actual error. If you have an error message, you should also include the traceback ( stack trace ).

Comment: @HåkenLid, I'm sorry i forget to show all my render. I'm already update my question and i hope can get the working code, because i'm really newbie. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch's Promises are asyncronous, so it's possible for the second request to finish before the first.

If the second request returns first, you have a state of this shape:

```
{
  isLoaded: true,
  tickerBtcIdr: undefinded,
  tickerBchIdr: { ... },
  ...
}
```

But your render function expects both `tickerBtcIdr` and `tickerBchIdr` to contain data when `isLoaded` is truthy.

Since you want both data sets in your render, you can't set `isLoaded` to be true after just receiving one request. The simplest solution is to just check for data instead of using a untrustworthy `isLoading` value.

In your render function, you can change this:

```
else if (!isLoaded)
```

to

```
else if (!(tickerBtcIdr && tickerBchIdr))
```

If you really want to use `isLoading` you can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which makes it possible to wait for both fetch requests before setting `isLoading` to true.